# A problem with a vector field on a convex set of $\mathbb{R}^3$ .

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given a vector function $Q$:$\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $. $S$ is a closed convex set and $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector normal to the surface $\partial S$ pointing outwards. $Q$ is not constant and is non-vanishing in $S$ and  $P=\{p\in \partial S:Q=\alpha\hat{n} , \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$.

**Under what conditions does $P$ has only one element ?**

you can impose any conditions you need e.g. smoothness, analyticity , compactness or strict convexity .

Comment: Is this vector function continuous? (I have only taken courses in vector calculus, analysis, and open set topology, so I’m sorry if my question is irrelevant.)

Comment: @BenjaminWang : you can add any conditions you need.

Comment: Certainly none of the normal "well behaved" conditions you list will *imply* that $P$ contains only one point, though there may or may not be specific vector fields which have this property. Are you looking for necessary or sufficient conditions?

Comment: @Kajelad: sufficient conditions